# Can't call Gradle with arguments from a java app using Process Builder, build fails

Tags: java, gradle, processbuilder, gradlew

I'm trying to call a Gradle app from a separate java app, on Linux. I'm using ProcessBuilder, which calls the Gradle app no problem when not passing an argument, and the Gradle app builds. But when I include an argument, it doesn't appear to run Gradle at all, but doesn't give an error, and still prints `Processbuilder run` to the Terminal.

This is in the main method:

```
        String cmd = "./gradlew";

        try {
            String lines = null;

            //This works but doesn't send an argument:
            //ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd, "run"); 

            //won't run with an argument!
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd, "run", "argy"); 

            Process pr = pb.start();

            System.out.println("Processbuilder run");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            while ((lines = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println("Line: " + lines);
            }
            

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { 
            System.out.print("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    

    }
```

Terminal output when run ProcessBuilder without `argy` :

```
    Processbuilder run
    Line: > Task :app:compileJava
    Line: > Task :app:processResources
    Line: > Task :app:classes
    Line: 
    Line: > Task :app:run
    Line: 
    Line: BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
    Line: 3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
`
```

Terminal output when run ProcessBuilder with `argy` :

```
    Processbuilder run
```

I need to pass java objects through so I can't use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` as it only passes through a string as an argument.

How can I get ProcessBuilder to supply the argument to Gradle and have it run? Or is there some other way of calling a Gradle app from a totally separate java package?

Comment: You aren't reading the `Process`'s error stream, which may be why you don't see any error but also don't see any expected output. You can do `pb.redirectErrorStream()` to redirect the process's error stream to its output stream. What do you see if you do that?

Comment: You may also want to check out the [Gradle Tooling API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/third_party_integration.html#embedding).

Comment: Once I had redirected the error stream, I realised it wasn't passing `--arg="argy"`, just `"argy"`. 
So I added 
`String myArgVar = "argy";`, 
`String myArg = String.format("--args=\" %s", myArgVar);` and myArg instead of "argy" in the `processBuilder` section and it worked. Alas it only takes String arguments as user16320675 pointed out so I'm now wading around the Gradle Tooling API, thanks Slaw! I think that's more what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After placing `pb.redirectErrorStream(true)`; before `pb.start()`, it became clear that I was passing "argy" as a command not an argument.
To run gradle, you need the command `./gradlew run --args="string_args"` so I edited it to:

```
        String argy= "argybargy\"";
        String myArg = String.format("--args=\" %s", argy);


        try {
            String lines = null;

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./gradlew", "run", myArg);

            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process pr = pb.start();
            System.out.println("Processbuilder run");

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            while ((lines = reader.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println("Line: " + lines);
            } 
            

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { 
            System.out.print("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Which now runs, passes the argument correctly, and redirects any errors to the terminal. Many thanks for all the help.